# connect to SQL server without domain

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I'm working on windows app. in .NET 2008 and I want to connect to SQL server 2008 installed on Windows Server in local net work, the problem is my client don't want to accomplish the connection via domain. is there any way to do this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server offers native authentication. Log into the server and create a local user.

More info here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx